# Compare dates are not returning correct results in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two dates in javascript

```
function checkCurrentDate(expiryDate){
//var currentDateStr=expiryDate;
var currentDate = new Date();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
currentDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
var dArr = currentDate.split("/");
currentDate = dArr[0]+ "/" +dArr[1]+ "/" +dArr[2].substring(2);  
var currentExpiryDateStr = expiryDate;

if(currentExpiryDateStr == currentDate){    

} 

if(currentExpiryDateStr < currentDate){

    alert("Expiry date is earlier than the current date.");
    return false;
}
}
```

currently the dates are in "currentExpiryDateStr " is "11/10/12" and "currentDate" is "11/8/12" now in this condition "if(currentExpiryDateStr < currentDate)" is returning true and is entering in if condition but this condition should return false and should not enter in this if condition. It was working before but dont know why it is not working now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add this 2 lines before your if condition

```
currentExpiryDateStr=Date.parse(currentExpiryDateStr);
currentDate=Date.parse(currentDate);
```

Comment: -1 Date.parse should not be used to parse strings as consistency across browsers is poor. It is especially bad to supply a non–standard format. If it is to be used at all, then a format [consistent with ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) (e.g. ISO8601) should be used, though it will fail in some browsers and the result should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object will do what you want - construct one for each date, then just compare them using the usual operators.
try this..

```
function checkCurrentDate(expiryDate){

   var currentDate = new Date();  // now date object

  var currentExpiryDateStr = new Date(expiryDate);  //expiry date object

   if(currentExpiryDateStr == currentDate){    

   } 

   if(currentExpiryDateStr < currentDate){

         alert("Expiry date is earlier than the current date.");
         return false;
    }
   }
```

here is the fiddle:: http://jsfiddle.net/YFvAC/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = Date.now();
if (expiryDate.getTime() < currentDate ) {
    alert("Expiry date is earlier than the current date.");
    return false;
}
```

The `now()` method returns the milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up until now as a number.

The `getTime()` returns the Milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, you should be comparing date objects.

If the expriy date is '11/10/12' in the format month/day/year and that the year is a two digit year after 2000, you can convert that to a date using:

```
function mdyToDate(dateString) {
  var b = dateString.split(/\D/);
  return new Date('20' + b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
}
```

To test expiry, you can do something like:

```
function hasExpired(dateString) {
  var expiryDate = mdyToDate(dateString);
  var now = new Date();
  return now > expiryDate;
}
```

So on 8-Nov-2012:

```
hasExpired('11/10/12'); // 10-Nov-2012 -- false
hasExpired('6/3/12');   // 03-Jun-2012 -- true
```

The `hasExpired` function can be replace with:

```
if (new Date() > mdyToDate(dateString)) {
  // dateString has expired
}
```

Comment: Rob i am seeing your method as well but having one problem. if i check the equal(==) condition. Then it fails because it is also comparing time.

Comment: i think i will use getTime()